# How can one view debug logs in Semantic-UI-React?

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Semantic-UI-React emits debug logs: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/src/modules/Modal/Modal.js#L162

But I don't see them in my browser.  I'm using semantic-ui-react 0.76.0.  In my local npm version of semantic-ui-react, the debug lines seem to be stripped out.  Is there some debug build I need?  Or maybe I need to set some webpack configuration?

Answer (score 0):

These logs are accesible only within development build of SUIR, they [are striped](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/v0.77.2/build/preset-es2015.js#L4) from any npm build by babel-plugin.

You can import component directly from `src` with such import:

```
import Modal from 'semantic-ui-react/src/modules/Modal';
```

Your builder will build component with all non-transformed code and you will can [enable it](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/v0.77.2/src/lib/debug.js#L12) with browser console:

```
localStorage.debug = '*'
```

Also, you we will to make a page reload after this.

---

Don't do this with your production builds :)

Comment: I attempted this, and got the following error `./node_modules/semantic-ui-react/src/modules/Dropdown/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:20)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| export default from './Dropdown'` . --- I also tried to follow the directions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hitchcott/semantic-ui-react#debugger) and that didn't work as well... Any suggestions?

Comment: You should configure your webpack to allow load files from node_modules.

Comment: Ah, I'm using create-react-app, and I don't want to eject, so I assume making that change would require ejecting...